# Error using ALTER TABLE users DISABLE KEYS statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following Mysql statement on MySQL Community Server - 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS moviedb;
USE moviedb;
CREATE TABLE creditcards (
id varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
first_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
last_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
expiration date DEFAULT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE creditcards DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO creditcards VALUES ('001', 'Tom', 'Hanks', '0000-00-00');
INSERT INTO creditcards VALUES ('002', 'Sandra', 'Bullock', '0000-00-00');
INSERT INTO creditcards VALUES ('003', 'Alan', 'Rickman', '0000-00-00');
CREATE TABLE stars (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
last_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
dob date DEFAULT NULL,
photo_url varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
INSERT INTO stars VALUES (755011, 'Arnold', 'Schwarzeneggar', '1947-07-30', 'http://www.imdb.com/gallery/granitz/2028/Events/2028/ArnoldSchw_Grani_1252920_400.jpg?path=pgallery&path_key=Schwarzenegger,%20Arnold');
INSERT INTO stars VALUES (755017, 'Eddie', 'Murphy', '1961-04-03', 'http://www.imdb.com/gallery/granitz/2487/Events/2487/EddieMurph_Pimen_2724994_400.jpg?path=pgallery&path_key=Murphy,%20Eddie%20(I)');
```

I know here must be an issue either with the syntax or one of the statements which might be causing an issue with the others. I am getting the following errors:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE creditcards DISABLE KEYS' at line 7
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'moviedb.creditcards' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'moviedb.creditcards' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'moviedb.creditcards' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO stars VALUES (755011, 'Arnold', 'Schwarzeneggar', '1947-07-30', 'htt' at line 9
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'moviedb.stars' doesn't exist
```

It appears the issue is with the `ALTER TABLE creditcards DISABLE KEYS;` statement. However, I do not know what is the issue here. The online documentation is no help on this point.

tried sqlfluff lint

Comment: There aren't any keys in creditcards to disable, every mysql statement must have a terminator, a CREATE is a statement, and must be terminated.. please publish the result of select version();

Answer (score -1):

As Per MySQL,

The DISABLE KEYS syntax is not valid in MySQL. This was used on other databases like MariaDB or Oracle's MySQL Cluster, but not in MySQL.

To disable keys in MySQL, you can use the ALTER TABLE statement with the DISABLE KEYS clause. Here's the answer:

```html
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS moviedb;
USE moviedb;
CREATE TABLE creditcards (
id varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
first_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
last_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
expiration date DEFAULT NULL
);
**ALTER TABLE creditcards DISABLE KEYS;**
INSERT INTO creditcards VALUES ('001', 'Tom', 'Hanks', '0000-00-00');
INSERT INTO creditcards VALUES ('002', 'Sandra', 'Bullock', '0000-00-00');
INSERT INTO creditcards VALUES ('003', 'Alan', 'Rickman', '0000-00-00');
CREATE TABLE stars (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
last_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
dob date DEFAULT NULL,
photo_url varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO stars VALUES (755011, 'Arnold', 'Schwarzeneggar', '1947-07-30', 'http://www.imdb.com/gallery/granitz/2028/Events/2028/ArnoldSchw_Grani_1252920_400.jpg?path=pgallery&path_key=Schwarzenegger,%20Arnold');
INSERT INTO stars VALUES (755017, 'Eddie', 'Murphy', '1961-04-03', 'http://www.imdb.com/gallery/granitz/2487/Events/2487/EddieMurph_Pimen_2724994_400.jpg?path=pgallery&path_key=Murphy,%20Eddie%20(I)');
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: ??You can use the ALTER TABLE statement with the DISABLE KEYS clause - that's what OP did..

Comment: Probably a ChatGPT generated answer.

Comment: It was not. I have already does in my previous codebase. Based on that I prepare that and submitted this solution.